# How to include order pictures in order_confirmation email?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, order-email, ecommerce-tracking

I am new to Magento and I am trying to find a way how to include a picture of the product the customer ordered from my website in the order confirmation email?

Answer (score 2):

You have file: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

Copy this file to your package/theme and add this piece of code below of foreach:

```
<?php 
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())
                ->load($_item->getProductId());
?>
```

Add this code to show image of product:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
                 ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>" 
 alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Where is app/design.../default.phtml is normally located in Magento admin panel? Thank you!

Comment: Is a magento filesystem design basis: http://blog.nodwell.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/theme-design-tree.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Maegento  does not save `product image on Sales Item  model(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item)`  That why you cannot get image from s`ales item` .

If you need  then `with out product Model load` you cannot get it at email

So you need add below code at  `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml`

```
<?php 

$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
               $_product ->setStoreId($_item->getOrder()->getStoreId())

                ->load($_item->getProductId());
// check product id is exit or not
if($_product->getId()):
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config') ->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>" 
 alt="<?php echo $_pr->getName() ?>" />

endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Get Image in sale order email

Please view below code :

1. $_item = $block->getItem();
2. $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
3. $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
4. $imageHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
5. $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($_product->getFile())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();

End add : `<img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" alt="" />`

---

Good look !